# npm "Invalid response body while trying to fetch". Can't install any dependencies using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

Good day everyone! I recently got this message:

> npm WARN config global --global, --local are deprecated. Use --location=global instead

I took care of this problem by editing the 4 necessary files (npm, npm.cmd, npx, npx.cmd).
Problem is, now I can't install any dependency and I can't use npx (for example for `npx create-react-app my-app`).

[When trying to install a dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcBN3.png)

[Running npx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAPhM.png)

What I have tried so far:

- `npm cache clean –force`
- `npm chache verify`
- Deleted the `npm-cache` folder under `'C:\Users\reaga\AppData\Local\`
- Completely uninstalled Nodejs and reinstalled the LTS
- Completely uninstalled Nodejs and reinstalled the current version
- Changed the `npm-cache` folder's location using `npm config set cache C:\reaga\nodejs\npm-cache --global`
- Deactivated antivirus
- Prayed to 17 different gods

On the flip side yarn seems to be working so I have no problems running `yarn add express` for example. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm "Invalid response body while trying to fetch". npm can't install any dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72856997/npm-invalid-response-body-while-trying-to-fetch-npm-cant-install-any-depende)