# npm "Invalid response body while trying to fetch". npm can't install any dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

Good day everyone! I recently worked through this error message:

> npm WARN config global --global, --local are deprecated. Use --location=global instead

by editing the 4 necessary files (npm, npm.cmd, npx, npx.cmd).
Problem is, now I can't install any dependency and I can't use npx (for example for `npx create-react-app my-app`).

[When trying to install a dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcBN3.png)

[Running npx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAPhM.png)

What I have tried so far:

- `npm cache clean –force`
- `npm chache verify`
- Deleted the `npm-cache` folder under `'C:\Users\reaga\AppData\Local\`
- Completely uninstalled Nodejs and reinstalled the LTS
- Completely uninstalled Nodejs and reinstalled the current version
- Changed the `npm-cache` folder's location using `npm config set cache C:\reaga\nodejs\npm-cache --global`
- Deactivated antivirus
- Prayed to 18 different gods

On the flip side yarn seems to be working so I have no problems running `yarn add express` for example. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The solution I followed to solve this problem:

`1` - Go to folder `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

`2` - You have to edit 4 files named : npm, npm.cmd, npx, npx.cmd

`3` - Open the files in a text editor, like [ Visual Studio Code ]

`4` - Replace prefix `-g with prefix` with `location=global` in all 4 files,
make sure didn't use -- and
Save all (if asked, save as administrator)

Like a picture.

Good to go!

(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/104328686/179422998-5b3f36c8-6b03-4b2b-95be-36f1cf3a2d80.PNG)

Comment: Did not work for me.